# Why does capacitor never fully discharge in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, charge

I've found in the following circuit, when the value of RPD is very high (say 10MΩ), sometimes the capacitor actually never fully discharges and the mosfet stays partially on. The LED dims but never completely turns off.

For lower values of that resistor (say 100kΩ) it fades off completely as expected.

What's going on here?

[image: circuit]

Comment: Probably leakage current from ESD protection structure on the gate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some leakage from the channel of the FET to the gate:

[image]

There might be additional leakage across the PCB itself, especially if you used a no-clean process, or left some flux residue on the board after hand soldering.

With 100 nA leakage, through a 10 megohm drain resistor, there could be up to 1 V on the gate. This is more than the 0.8 V minimum for the gate threshold voltage, so it's not surprising the FET channel remains at least somewhat conductive.

Comment: yup, measured it and there's about 1V on the gate.

Comment: @JHalcres, I'm surprised that connecting a multimeter doesn't change the result in this case.

Comment: How can I correct for this? I suppose the only thing I can do is use a bigger capacitor and smaller resistor.

Comment: @JHalcres, smaller resistor. If this is a correct analysis, then even 1 megohm should be low enough to prevent the problem.

Comment: If you still see the issue with 1 megohm at RPD, then you might need to look for things like capacitive interference being rectified by a bad solder joint or something.

Comment: You might also look for a FET with lower leakage current, and be sure your board is well cleaned if you want to stick with 10 megohms.

Comment: I changed it to 2MΩ and I think it actually got *worse*...

Comment: @JHalcres, can you edit your post to include a photo of the physical circuit?